# Powershell - Checking if an Azure AD guest already exists

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

We have a Powershell script that invites guests in bulk to Azure AD. The email addresses are contained in a CSV file.

It is all working well, but I would like to add functionality to check if the user already exists in the tenant, so that they don't receive a second invitation (it seems you can continue to invite already existing or already invited guests).

For a normal user like `bob@company.com`, with

```
$email = "bob@company.com"
```

I could simply use this:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "$email"
```

Of course guests are formatted like `john_gmail.com#EXT#tenant.onmicrosoft.com`. Using that as the `ObjectID` does indeed work correctly, but of course in the CSV we would see `john@gmail.com` and so it fails to look up the user.

Is there some sensible way to convert `john@email.com` to `john_gmail.com#EXT#tenant.onmicrosoft.com` whilst doing this lookup? It needs to be seen as a normal email address later in the script when it actually invites them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `$email = "john@email.com"` you can search for `"john_gmail.com#EXT#tenant.onmicrosoft.com"` like this:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "$($email -replace "@", "_")#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
```

or

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId ($email.Replace("@","_") + "#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com")
```

This doesn't change the value of `$email` while you can still search for the expanded term.

Comment: Thanks, but the @ needs to change to an underscore for it to work.

Comment: And sorry, I forgot the @ before the tenant name in john_gmail.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com. But regardless, the initial @ before gmail.com needs to be _ before I can get it to work. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've realised I can use

`$email -replace "@", "_"`

To get the output I want. I'll duplicate the variable to avoid causing issues or having to revert it later in the script.

Comment: You don't need to make another variable, edited my answer to solve this.