# Azure AD Graph API does not reliably tell me if a guest user already exists

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Before I send a guest invite (or make other decisions), I need to know if the email address is already in use. Right now it appears the only option I have is to check by filtering the `/users` API by mail `$filter=mail eq 'example@example.com'`

However, once an invite is sent, I noticed it takes sometimes more than 10 seconds to complete. So if I make another request beforehand, my code checking `if(user.exists()` returns `false` which causes unexpected behavior in code.. Because technically the user is there now. But the API doesn't immediately return the results that I need.

One of the possible solutions may be to convert the guest account's email to the `UPN` generated by Azure... I was looking into the suggestion referenced in [Powershell - Checking if an Azure AD guest already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946089/powershell-checking-if-an-azure-ad-guest-already-exists)

Is there a better solution? Is it reliable to change every `@` symbol to `_` and append `#EXT#` so that I can instead search the user by it's principal name (which I believe would give me the accurate answer right away) `/users/{upn}`

Answer (score 2):

The PowerShell script you are referring it is feasible solution you can use in your code.

> if(user.exists() returns false which causes unexpected behavior in
> code.

Make sure the user is searching for, it is no longer available with it original email id in Azure AD because it has converted from `$email = "john@email.com"`  to `upn="john_gmail.com#EXT#tenant.onmicrosoft.com"` when you invited.

So, Checking of your user existence is based on UPN not based on original email id.

You can use any concept of PowerShell Script provided in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946089/powershell-checking-if-an-azure-ad-guest-already-exists) to first replace `@` to `_` and append `#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`. Then search based on UPN.